# Enforce generic types in java property declaration

Tags: java, generics

Java code:

```
class First {}
class Second extends First {}
class Jinkies<T> {}
interface Greeting<T> {}
class Hello<U extends T, T> implements Greeting<T> {
  private Map<Jinkies<U>, List<U>> scooby;
}
```

In the declaration of `scooby`, both `Jinkies` and `List` have the same type parameter - that's what I want to enforce. Is there a way to achieve this in Java without having to resort to listing two parameters (`U` and `T`) in the declaration of `Hello` class?

I'd like to have only one - e.g. something like:

```
class Hello<U extends T> implements Greeting<T>
```

however, that doesn't compile. I have to write:

```
new Hello<Second, First>()
```

instead of:

```
new Hello<Second>()
```

even though I don't care about `First` anywhere in the body of `Hello` (nor do the users of `Hello`).

Edit - as @LouisWasserman explains in the comment, bad example on my part above. Maybe to clarify - let's say I always want to do:

```
new Hello<First>()
```

but then be able to use any `U` where `U extends First` (i.e. `First` or `Second` in the above example) throughout the body of `Hello` without caring for `First` and with making sure that `U` is always the same. That is, if I had two methods:

```
void method1(U a) {}
void method2(U b) {}
```

I'd like to be able to enforce that `U` of the first method is the same as the `U` of the second method - but **not** care about what it is (i.e. `First` or `Second`), as long as it is the same.

```
<U extends T> void method1(U a) {}
<U extends T> void method2(U b) {}
```

would not work, as I could call `method1(first)` and `method2(second)`.

Edit - thinking this through, this probably would not work the other way. I.e. if only specifying one bound, it would be possible to go the other way. So if specifying `First` only, I could "downcast" to a `Third`. If specifying `Second` only, I could "upcast" to a `Zero`. Back to the laboratory...

Comment: If you wrote `new Hello<Second>`, then what `Greeting<T>` would it implement?  How would you know?  It sounds like `Greeting` shouldn't have a `T` at all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman `Greeting<T>` having a `T` is needed for other reasons. I agree `new Hello<Second>()` would not work for the reasons you mention - bad example on my part. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same class definition, but maybe it is more visible now with different generic names :

```
class Jinkies<X> {}
interface Greeting<Y> {}
class Hello<T,U extends T> implements Greeting<T> {
  private Map<Jinkies<U>, List<U>> scooby;
}
```

As you can see, without specifing `T` in declaration like `new Hello<Second, First>()`, you cannot say what `T` is.